# Postgresql - retrieving referenced fields in a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table created like

```
CREATE TABLE data
(value1 smallint references labels,
 value2 smallint references labels,
 value3 smallint references labels,
 otherdata varchar(32)
);
```

and a second 'label holding' table created like

```
CREATE TABLE labels (id serial primary key, name varchar(32));
```

The rationale behind it is that value1-3 are a very limited set of strings (6 options) and it seems inefficient to enter them directly in the data table as varchar types. On the other hand these do occasionally change, which makes enum types unsuitable.

My question is, how can I execute a single query such that instead of the label IDs I get the relevant labels?
I looked at creating a function for it and stumbled at the point where I needed to pass the label holding table name to the function (there are several such (label holding) tables across the schema). Do I need to create a function per label table to avoid that?

```
create or replace function translate
(ref_id smallint,reference_table regclass) returns varchar(128) as
$$           
begin
select name from reference_table where id = ref_id;
return name;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And then do

```
select
    translate(value1, labels) as foo,
    translate(value2, labels) as bar
from data;
```

This however errors out with

```
ERROR:  relation "reference_table" does not exist
```

All suggestions welcome - at this point a can still alter just about anything...

Comment: could you expand your question to include "sample data" and "expected result"? t this stage I'm struggling to visualize what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE labels
  ( id smallserial primary key
  , name varchar(32) UNIQUE -- <<-- might want this, too
  );

CREATE TABLE data
 ( value1 smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES labels(id) -- <<-- here
 , value2 smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES labels(id)
 , value3 smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES labels(id)
 , otherdata varchar(32)
 , PRIMARY KEY (value1,value2,value3) -- <<-- added primary key here
);

-- No need for a function here.
-- For small sizes of the `labels` table, the query below will always
-- result in hash-joins to perform the lookups.

SELECT l1.name AS name1, l2.name AS name2, l3.name AS name3
        , d.otherdata AS the_data
FROM data d
JOIN labels l1 ON l1.id = d.value1
JOIN labels l2 ON l2.id = d.value2
JOIN labels l3 ON l3.id = d.value3
        ;
```

Note: `labels.id -> labels.name` is a functional dependency (id is the primary key), but that doesn't mean that you need a function. The query just *acts* like a function.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks! As simple as it looks now, I didn't think of passing different short names for the same table, which then enables you to have different joining keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the label table name as string, construct a query as string and `execute` it:

```
sql = `select name from ` || reference_table_name || `where id = ` || ref_id;
EXECUTE sql INTO name;
RETURN name;
```